# Как в linux bash измерить время работы процесса

Tags: linux, bash

У меня есть задание - вывести через скрипт имя пользователя и его pid, если процесс является спящим и работает больше минуты. Я понимаю как сделать так, чтобы найти все спящие процессы, но как определить время, я не знаю

```
#! /bin/bash

container="$(ps u | awk '{ if ($1=="root" && $8=="S") print $0 }')"

echo "$container" | awk '{ if (...) print $1 ":" $2 }'
```

Comment: попробуйте поискать информацию в интернете

Comment: Время работы или время с момента запуска?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле номер `$8` если не содержит  `0:`, то процесс работает больше минуты.